# Is it safe to delete C:\$Windows.~WS?

Tags: windows-8.1

I joined Windows 10 upgrade program, but due to various reasons I decided to stay with Windows 8.1 and not upgrade. Now it seems, that I have a pretty big (almost 6GB) folder at C:\$Windows.~WS.

I ran disk cleanup tool, but it didn't remove this particular folder.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can delete that folder. I have decided not to upgrade as well and deleted both **$Windows.~BT** and **$Windows.~WS** folders.

Comment: Well, $Windows.~BT is removed automatically when you run disk cleanup tool.

Comment: Good to know. I haven't used that in a while.